# How do I get the results of multiple comboboxes?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

So I am trying to get all of the selected values in comboboxes after I press the submit button. The tricky part is that I have an 'add combobox' button that adds a new combobox for a certain section. I want to know how I can get the selected value from every combobox even the ones that were added. Any ideas?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

window = Tk()
window.title('Price Calc')
window.geometry('900x650')

ym = 0
yh = 1

tH = []

cart = []

material = {
    'Kydex SC 12x12' : 13.00,
    'Kydex SC 8x8' : 10.00,
    'Kydex CFB' : 16.00,
    'Kydex CG' : 16.00
}
hardware = {
    'Eyelets' : 0.15,
    'Slotted Post' : 0.75,
    'TH Screw' : 0.50,
    'Spacer .25' : 0.50,
    'Spacer .50' : 0.30,
    'Db Spacer' : 0.25,
    'Washer' : 0.15,
    'Fin Washers' : 0.15
}
mounting = {
    'P Paddle S' : 11.00,
    'P Paddle L' : 12.00,
    'AB Loop 1.50"' : 6.00,
    'AB Loop 1.75"' : 7.00,
    'Wings 1.75"' : 5.00,
    'S Clips 1.75"' : 8.50
}
labor = 30.00

def addm():
    global ym, yh

    ym += 1

    Combobox(window, values=list(material.keys())).grid(column=1, row=ym, pady=10)

    ih = h.grid_info()
    ihr = ih['row'] + 1
    h.grid(sticky=W, column=0, row=ihr, pady=10)

    ihl = hl.grid_info()
    ihlr = ihl['row'] + 1
    hl.grid(column=1, row=ihlr, padx=5)

    iah = ah.grid_info()
    iahr = iah['row'] + 1
    ah.grid(column=2, row=iahr)

    yh += 1

def addh():
    global yh
    global cV

    yh += 1

    cV = Combobox(window, values=list(hardware.keys()))
    cV.grid(column=1, row=yh, pady=10)

    

def Calculate():
    tH.append(hl.get(), cV.get())
    print(str(tH))

m = Label(window, text='Material', font=('Arial 11')).grid(sticky=W, column=0, row=0, pady=10)
ml = Combobox(window, state='readonly')
ml['values'] = list(material.keys())
ml.grid(column=1, row=0)

am = Button(window, text='Add', command=addm).grid(column=2, row=0)

h = Label(window, text='Hardware', font=('Arial 11'))
h.grid(sticky=W, column=0, row=1, pady=10)
hl = Combobox(window, state='readonly')
hl['values'] = list(hardware.keys())
hl.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=5)

ah = Button(window, text='Add', command=addh)
ah.grid(column=2, row=1)

c = Button(window, text='Calculate', command=Calculate)
c.grid(column = 3, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Please also let me know of anything I can do to improve the efficiency of my code.

Comment: Create another list after `cart = []` like `comboboxes = []` and save each new `Combobox` in there, e.g. `comboboxes.append(cV)`. Also, use more descriptive variable names - there's no reason to limit them to one or two letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your comboboxes to a list as you make them, then you can loop through them later. I see you have a cart variable already, that will do nicely.

> let me know of anything I can do to improve the efficiency of my code.

Well, since you ask: you can also make a new Frame to put the comboboxes in. That way you don't have to keep track of the rows.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

window = Tk()
window.title('Price Calc')
window.geometry('900x650')

material = {
    'Kydex SC 12x12' : 13.00,
    'Kydex SC 8x8' : 10.00,
    'Kydex CFB' : 16.00,
    'Kydex CG' : 16.00
}
hardware = {
    'Eyelets' : 0.15,
    'Slotted Post' : 0.75,
    'TH Screw' : 0.50,
    'Spacer .25' : 0.50,
    'Spacer .50' : 0.30,
    'Db Spacer' : 0.25,
    'Washer' : 0.15,
    'Fin Washers' : 0.15
}
mounting = {
    'P Paddle S' : 11.00,
    'P Paddle L' : 12.00,
    'AB Loop 1.50"' : 6.00,
    'AB Loop 1.75"' : 7.00,
    'Wings 1.75"' : 5.00,
    'S Clips 1.75"' : 8.50
}
labor = 30.00

def addm():
    ml = Combobox(material_frame, values=list(material.keys()))
    ml.grid(column=1, pady=10)
    cart.append(ml)

def addh():
    cV = Combobox(hardware_frame, values=list(hardware.keys()))
    cV.grid(column=1, pady=10)
    cart.append(cV)

def Calculate():
    for box in cart:
        print(box.get())

cart = []

material_frame = Frame(window)
material_frame.grid(column=1, row=0)
addm() # make the first combobox
Label(material_frame, text='Material', font=('Arial 11')).grid(sticky=W, column=0, row=0, pady=10)
Button(material_frame, text='Add', command=addm).grid(column=2, row=0)

hardware_frame = Frame(window)
hardware_frame.grid(column=1, row=1)
addh()
h = Label(hardware_frame, text='Hardware', font=('Arial 11'))
h.grid(sticky=W, column=0, row=0, pady=10)
ah = Button(hardware_frame, text='Add', command=addh)
ah.grid(column=2, row=0)

c = Button(window, text='Calculate', command=Calculate)
c.grid(column = 3, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```